# miscalculation of top x% this week/month/quarter/year/overall

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In [cogsci.stackexchange.com](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/), my [profile page](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/421/john-pick) shows an unexpectedly high value of x in "top x% this week", and I've noticed that section of my profile was quite lowballed (highballed?) several other times too. And note that I am counting only active users in each time period; those with 0 reputation during the period do not count.

Current text:

> top 38% this week

Correct text would be:

> top 11% this week

The website is new and has only a few active users. Could those 2 facts have something to do with it?

How do we get the calculation fixed?

Comment: Technically, if you're among the top 11%, you're among the top 38% ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer True. I will edit the question.

Comment: Based on the [actual list](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/179/week/cogsci/2012-04-01/421#421), you're 3rd of 8, which makes the "top 38%" correct. Where did you count additional users from that you got 11% as the expected value?

Comment: @TimeStone Thanks. That list doesn't seem to jibe with http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week though. The latter page shows I'm tied for 1st out of 18 users.

Comment: Ah, the latter is real-time (more or less), the x% in your profile are daily. Wait until tomorrow. - At least, that's how it is on SO.

Comment: Strangely, my reputation week-to-date on http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week is correct, but that of http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/376/catharsis is too low (107 instead of 202). However, note that Catharsis has a 100-point Association Bonus, which almost accounts for the discrepancy.

Comment: And now I finally see the fine print: "users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues" -- aha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Stone and Daniel Fischer, I now see there's more involved in the calculation than meets the eye:

- users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues
- stats are updated daily, not continuously

With those two pieces of info, I was able to reconcile the "top 38% this week".